# How can I create a dict with keys that contain multiple values from two lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a text file that contains the following data:

```
C1,0,0,0,0,0,10
C2,5,5,0,5,5,10
C3,10,10,0,10,10,10
```

I am bringing this data into my Python script with the ultimate goal of having it in the following format:

```
columnCoordDict = {'C1': [0,0,0,0,0,10], 'C2': [5,5,0,5,5,10], 'C3': [10,10,0,10,10,10]}
```

My method so far has been to bring the data into my script and then split it into two lists:

List 1 - a list containing the keys ('C1' ,'C2', 'C3').
List 2 - a list containing the values (which represent x, y, z coords).

```
# Reading text file with frame data
frameData = open("frameData.txt","r")


data = frameData.read()
data = data.replace("\n", ",")
dataList = data.split(',')

# Creating list containing keys alone by slicing
dataListKeys = dataList[::7]

# Creating list containing values by list comprehension removing Keys from main list
dataListValues = [x for x in dataList if x not in dataListKeys]

dictData = {}
```

However, I am unsure now how to create the dict in the format I presented above. I tried a zip method where it produced:

```
{'C1': 0, 'C2': 0, 'C3': 0}
```

But I need multiple values to be assigned to each key. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: accept any of the answers to make the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get the wanted result with this:

```
frameData = open("frameData.txt","r")
data = frameData.read().splitlines()
frameData.close()
columnCoordDict = {}

for line in data:
  items = line.split(',')
  columnCoordDict[items[0]] = list(map(lambda x: int(x), items[1:]))

print(columnCoordDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
frameData = open("frameData.txt","r")
dictData = {i.split(",")[0]: list(map(int, i.split(",")[1:])) for i in frameData.readlines()}
frameData.close()
```